# Testing a post API call that has a param with Postman

Tags: node.js, api, postman

This is my API route in nodejs:

```
router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      res.json('Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      //return res.j('/forgot');
    }
    res.json('Goed');
  });
});
```

Now when I want to test this in Postman, I use this incorrect way:

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUqhi.png)

I normally don't work with params, how can I test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues.
1. In screen shot the method is `POST` but your code waiting for `GET` request. 
2. use this url: `http://localhost:3000/reset/6b...`. do not use `token=`

Comment: Lol why did I not see the Get! Forgot to switch it, late night I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use URL segment parameters like this:

URL: `http://localhost:3000/reset/:id`

And a URL parameter:

`id` = `65bb...`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the token as the last part of the path, like so:

```
localhost:3000/reset/65bb...
```

Optionally, if you want to pass the token as a query parameter (like you do in your Postman screenshot), define the route like this:

```
router.get('/reset', function(req, res) {
   // In here, use req.query.token instead of req.params.token
}
```